# inserting nested dictonary in MongoDB

Tags: python, mongodb, dictionary, pymongo, crud

so im trying to insert a nested dictionary into my mongodb connection
i tried

```
collectio.insert(data), collection.insert_one(data), collectio.insert_many(data)
```

my data looks like this :

```
{
   "1616004000":{
      "V1/V12_Voltage_0-Vmax":[
         0.0
      ],
      "V2/V23_Voltage_0-Vmax":[
         436.0
      ],
      "V3/V31_Voltage_0-Vmax":[
         494.0
      ],
      "I1_Current_0-Imax":[
         403.0
      ],
      "I2_Current_0-Imax":[
         0.0
      ],
      "I3_Current_0-Imax":[
         0.0
      ],
      "kW_L1_":[
         0.0
      ],
      "kW_L2_":[
         0.0
      ]
   }
}
```

the error i got was :

```
pymongo.errors.WriteConcernError: No write concern mode named 'manodeority' found in replica set configuration, full error: {'code': 79, 'codeName': 'UnknownReplWriteConcern', 'errmsg': "No write concern mode named 'manodeority' found in replica set configuration", 'errInfo': {'writeConcern': {'w': 'manodeority', 'wtimeout': 0, 'provenance': 'clientSupplied'}}}
```

any suggetions ?

Comment: You can use any of the three _insert_ methods to insert the dictionary: [PyMongo - Insert Documents](https://pymongo.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tutorial.html#inserting-a-document).

Comment: none of them work
the last error i got was:
pymongo.errors.WriteConcernError: No write concern mode named 'manodeority' found in replica set configuration, full error: {'code': 79, 'codeName': 'UnknownReplWriteConcern', 'errmsg': "No write concern mode named 'manodeority' found in replica set configuration", 'errInfo': {'writeConcern': {'w': 'manodeority', 'wtimeout': 0, 'provenance': 'clientSupplied'}}}

Comment: What kind of cluster is it? A replica-set? The error says `pymongo.errors.WriteConcernError` - you are using a _wrong_ `WriteConcern` option. Can you post the code where you are specifying the write concern? See what is [Write Concern](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/write-concern/).

Comment: im just creating a dictonary the same i posted just longer , and tryed using the 3 insert options

Comment: Write concern is a setting on your database server -  the error is about the write concern. Read about it in the link in my last comment. The setting can be at the cluster connection, database, collection or the write operation level.